# I am looking for a production alternative to kubectl port-forward

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, kubectl, minikube

I want to know what are production alternatives to make http://192.168.49.2:30001 this accessible http://host_machine_ip:8007 here

I have set up minikube cluster with mobile-api service on it.

```
minikube service mobile-api-service --url this returns http://192.168.49.2:30001
```

curl http://192.168.49.2:30001 returns

```
{"mobileApi/dashboard":"http://192.168.49.2:30001/mobileApi/dashboard/",
"mobileApi/notification":"http://192.168.49.2:30001/mobileApi/notification/",
"mobileApi/feedback":"http://192.168.49.2:30001/mobileApi/feedback/"}
```

so my API is accessible on http://192.168.49.2:30001 from the host machine.

but i want to make it accessible http://host_machine_ip:8007.

when I do

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/mobile-api-service 8007:8007
```

it makes http://host_machine_ip:8007 work as I want but I am sure this is not a production-like case.

### Update

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mobile-api-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mobile-api
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8007
      targetPort: 8007
      nodePort: 30001
```

this is service it is loadBalancer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make `service/mobile-api-service` of LoadBalancer type or use Kubernetes Ingress to expose the workload to external connectivity.  Using LoadBalancer service would be the easiest. However, your cloud provider needs to support provisioning LoadBalancers.

I described a [demo of Kubernetes Ingress](https://www.rokpoto.com/kubernetes-ingress-demo/). The post also talks about Kubernetes Load Balancer service limitations.

To play with [minikube loadbalancers](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#loadbalancer-access) use `minikube tunnel` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and experiment with [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) and use Loadbalancer service
Another option is to use node port with external Loadbalancer.